# how to set 3 divs side by side SO THAT the middle div can stretch with the form resize

Tags: css

I know this might look like an old question but Im trying to put 3 divs side by side  but the middle div should stretch with the form resizing. I found [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/TW4dn/) and used their code but it doesnt work. The right div still gets pushed down bellow the div instead of being next to it.

[Here](http://www.hydrocell.co/Huis.html) is an example of what I have but like I said the right div gets pushed down bellow the div instead of being next to it.
Can someone please share their well earned knowledge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainDiv{ position: relative;}
.left{ position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; }
.right{ position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; }
.center { margin: 0 100px; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/88Eff/1/)

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrH9Y/) as per your new requirement :)

Comment: Ok so now that this is kind-of working I would like to take it a step further. I want the div on the right to be right against the middle div irrespective of the middle divs length. At the moment the right div is "pinned" to the right of the browser window. Can you help?

Comment: The right div is still "pinned" to the right of the window (right:0; top:0;) please take a look at [this link](http://www.hydrocell.co/test2.html) to see what exactly it is I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; height:140px;">
<div style="width:100px; float:left; border:1px solid blue;">
    left
</div>
<div style="width:100px;  float:right; border:1px solid blue; ">
    right
</div>
<div style="border:5px solid green; overflow:hidden;">
    middle
</div>
```

check this example

Comment: Hi thanks for your example. If I add a margin-right: to your right div I do get a closer result. I also added a min-width to your middle div. How can I prevent the div's from pusshing down (causing a line break) when I make the browser window smaller

Comment: Ok [here](http://www.hydrocell.co/test2.html) is a link of the final result to give you exact idea